# a becomes z, b becomes y. abcd becomes zyxw ...etc in python

Tags: python, string

```
def string_transf():
    input('Enter a word or string')
    #letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz'
    #for i in letters:
            #i+=

    if c >= 'a' and c <='z':
        i = 'z' - c + 'a'
        print(i)
```

I tried to come up with an algorithm, but I'm lost.

Comment: Hint: use `ord(..)` and `chr(..)`.

Comment: Don't use `&` that is the bitwise and, use `and` which is the boolean and

Comment: sorry for that, was just a quick sketch @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't say you want to handle uppercase letters, here is a single line answer:

```
>>> ''.join(chr(122 - ord(c) + 97) for c in 'abcd')
'zyxw'
```

Where 122 is `ord('z')` and 97 is `ord('a')`. `ord` function converts the character to its Unicode code point and `chr` function does the opposite.

You can skip non lowercase characters if you will:

```
>>> ''.join(chr(122 - ord(c) + 97) for c in 'abcdEFG' if 'a' <= c <= 'z')
'zyxw'
```

If you want to handle uppercase following the same model:

```
>>> def inv(c):
...  if 'a' <= c <= 'z':
...   return chr(122 - ord(c) + 97)
...  if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
...   return chr(90 - ord(c) + 65)
...  return c
... 
>>> ''.join(inv(c) for c in 'Hello world!')
'Svool dliow!'
```

Comment: @macha Thanks :) . It's really close to what you got. You just needed to take advantage of `ord` and `chr` functions, so that Python knows what to add and subtract. Feel free to mark the question as answered if your problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach. 
Create a dictionary `my_map`, which describes the character's translation:

```
import string
ascii_alph = string.ascii_lowercase

my_map = dict(zip(ascii_alph, ascii_alph[::-1]))

str_input = 'abcd'
str_output = ''.join(my_map[c] for c in str_input) # assume every c in my_map

print(str_output) # zyxw
```

Also you can implement that with the `translate` method:

```
# my_map = string.maketrans(ascii_alph, ascii_alph[::-1]) # Python 2
my_map = str.maketrans(ascii_alph, ascii_alph[::-1]) # Python 3

str_input = 'abcd'
str_output = str_input.translate(my_map)

print(str_output) # zyxw
```

For the general case (ASCII uppercase and other chars) you can always expand `'my_map'` dictionary.

Note that the described approach is quite flexible since it allows you to make translation not only for the case of inversion of the alphabet.

Comment: If you are going to do that, you might as well use `str.translate`

Comment: Thank you very much @maximtitarenko I appreciate.

Comment: @macha, glad I could help.